# Can't get content from plist to UITableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, xcode6, plist

Hello i am getting this error and i can't find where is the problem

my code is this :

```
@implementation ViewController {
NSDictionary *animalDetails;
NSArray *justAnimalNames;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"animals"withExtension:@"plist"];
    animalDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
    justAnimalNames = animalDetails.allKeys;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. }
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return animalDetails.count; }
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = justAnimalNames [indexPath.row];

    return cell; }
```

And the error i am getting is in this line :

```
cell.textLabel.text = justAnimalNames [indexPath.row];
```

***property 'textLabel' not found on object of type 'UITableview'***

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cell` needs to be `UITableViewCell *` instead of `UITableView *`.

Comment: Also, to see anything happen, you will need to implement `-[numberOfSectionsInTableView:]` as well. Some curly braces also seem to be missing from your code.

Comment: if you don't implement numberOfSectionsInTableView, it is assumed there is one section.